# Microsoft Graph REST API not able to write mail

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using graph rest api for writing a draft mail.

First, I called the authorize method with the `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` scope:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient&response_mode=query&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

With the obtained code, I called the token method with the same scope:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

With this token, I am able to get messages without any issues, but when I try to create a draft by calling: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/` I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "7fafbb5a-ab6d-4dbc-bb73-69d58b00f7ac",
      "date": "2019-11-26T20:48:24"
    }
  }
}
```

As stated in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) I have set the `Mail.ReadWrite` permission in my registered Azure app and granted admin consent. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked Graph logs and that call to Microsoft Graph did not have the `Mail.ReadWrite` permission.  Can you try adding that permission to the `scope` query param in your implicit auth flow call instead of .default? (If you need multiple permissions you can list them all in the scope param separated by spaces)

Comment: It worked, thank you! Do you know the reason why was the permission not on the call despite being set in the Azure App? What is the difference bewteen setting the permissions at the scope level and the Azure App Application/Delegated permissions? I am new to Azure and those concepts are not clear to me yet

Comment: Awesome, glad it's working! In v2 auth, consent can either be granted by an end user (they'll see some consent screen asking if your app can access their account) or consent can be granted by a tenant admin on behalf of every user in their organization.  In Azure portal, you can add permissions to an app and consent to them so every user in your tenant doesn't need to since it's a trusted app